# The application stopped unexpectdly 

Tags: android

I had this message when running the project:

```
Unfortunately the project stopped
```

also when I add the code between try and catch I had this error

```
application dosenot define permission com.example.elarabygroup.permission.c2d MESSAGE
```

I tested all codes and I found the error to be here:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_elaraby_group);

    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    if (regId.equals("")) {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
    }
}
```

manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.elarabygroup"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ElarabyGroup"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_elaraby_group" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name=".ElarabyGroup" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>


</manifest>
```

GCMIntentService  class

```
package com.example.elarabygroup;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class GCMIntenetService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    public static String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntenetService(String senderId) {
        super(senderId);
        Log.d("GCMIntentService", senderId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("onError", arg1);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.d("onRecoverableError", errorId);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.d("onMessage", String.valueOf(arg1));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("onRegistered", arg1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("onUnregistered", arg1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's does your LogCat says?

Comment: I cannot find any errors on logcat

Comment: put a try catch block and log the exception

Comment: when I sopped with mouse cursor on GCMRegistrar I have this Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found

Comment: I had this error application dosenot define permission com.example.elarabygroup.permission.c2d MESSAGE

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Try this